# Equivalent to the Chinese quote, (mis)attributed to JFK: "We fear not God-like rivals, but pig-like team members"

Tags: translation, phrase-requests, quotes

I've been looking for an English equivalent of the Chinese, "不怕神一样的对手 就怕猪一样的队友," which has been, rather directly, translated as:

> We fear not God-like rivals, but pig-like team members

and rather funnily enough attributed to JFK.

- Did JFK ever say anything even remotely close to this?
- Are there other idiomatic phrases in English that resemble "We fear not God-like rivals, but pig-like team members"? (i.e: who needs enemies, with friends like *you*?)

Comment: A different U.S. president, Warren G. Harding, expressed a similar sentiment: "I have no trouble with my enemies. I can take care of my enemies all right. But my damn friends...They're the ones that keep me walking the floor nights."

Comment: Negli amici guarda mi Dio; negli nemmici mi guardo io. (This was taught to me decades ago by a new immigrant, so the spelling is not guaranteed.) Its meaning: Among my friends, God guards me; among my enemies, I guard myself.

Comment: Questions about whether someone said something are more usual on https://history.stackexchange.com/ but someone here might know.

Answer (score 2):

(With apologies and thanks to Janus)

> Keep your enemies close, but your friends closer.

It's sometimes used as an ironic twist on

Keep your friends close, but your enemies closer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quote, but it reads like a proverb.

> ***A strong foe is better than a weak friend***. ([Edward Dahlberg](https://www.azquotes.com/author/3578-Edward_Dahlberg))

I have also found other expressions of your version:

> A weak teammate does more harm than the enemy.

and

> What one should really fear is not a competent enemy, but an
> incompetent ally.

[Aside: I can't resist posting this quotation from [Oscar Wilde](https://www.azquotes.com/author/15644-Oscar_Wilde) which I found while doing research for this answer:

> Always forgive your enemies - nothing annoys them so much.]